# Why isn't my PlayerPrefs key detected across multiple games?

Tags: unity, c#

I am developing a level based game; I created a key in the PlayerPrefs class called *"LevelNumber"*. It's default value is 0. If I pass level one, it increments by 1 and goes on.

Everything is working fine, but if I press *"restart level"* or if I close and reopen the game menu, the key is no longer detected. Every time I restart the game, it is printing *"key not found"* in the console. How do I fix this?

```
public class AppController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int _currentLevel = 0;

    void Start ()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID && UNITY_EDITOR
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("LevelNumber")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Key Found");
            _currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("LevelNumber");
            levels [_currentLevel].SetActive (true);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Key not found");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("LevelNumber",_currentLevel);
            levels [_currentLevel].SetActive (true);
            timeText.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }
        #endif
    }

    public void nextLevelButtonClick()
    {
        int j = _currentLevel + 1;
        _currentLevel = j;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("LevelNumber",_currentLevel);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
    }

    public void RestartLevelButtonClick()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong?!?! but it worked for me.....if you recieved key not found every time means that there is no `"LevelNumber"` key
this problem will happen when your keys isn't match
e.g: `SetInt("LEVELNUMBER",0);   x = GetInt("levelnumber");`

but try saving level index instead of value:
 
`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelNumber",SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);`

Comment: i also checked it's independently working. is there is any chance that other script affect this key?

Comment: Note the changes I have made; UnityScript is a variant of JavaScript. This code is quite obviously C# (only as UnityScript does not use `: MonoBehaviour`), so I removed the [tag:unityscript] tag. I also see nothing relevant to MonoDevelop (that is just the compiler, but nothing you report occurs *because* of the compiler), so again, no need for that tag. @smkplus, I feel it is worth noting that I feel "inline coding" is *not* the correct format for direct quotes (names and such). Due to to the other obvious fixes in this question, this outright rejected your proposed edit.

Comment: .. Why don't you grab the value from the start? If I'm reading this right, your checking if the value exists before grabbing it. If it does not exist, we just go on from level one. If it does exist, we go on from wherever. Regardless, we are going to start with a number, and push that number back to the playerprefs. Why not just grab the number using the second variation of `PlayerPrefs.GetInt()`, i.e. `PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string name, int default)`? I don't think that it would fix your problem, but it removes some redundancy that makes this sort of problem more common and harder to debug.

Comment: Are you running the app on PC or on Android?

Comment: Why do you have the `#if UNITY_ANDROID && UNITY_EDITOR` directive surrounding this code? This code will be skipped over by the compiler when running/editing on your PC or Mac computer, since it's not Android, and skipped when generating a compiled build for Android, since it's not the editor. Meaning there's no platform where your key initialization code ever runs, unless I'm drastically misreading this...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're trying to check for a key that doesn't exist yet. Try getting the key and setting a default value in one line instead. Also, using the same line of code inside both the if and the else statement is redundant, something is wrong if you feel the need to do that. Try it this way instead (this will always go inside the if, and never run the else part):

```
_currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("LevelNumber", _currentLevel);
levels [_currentLevel].SetActive (true);
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("LevelNumber")) {
    Debug.Log("Key Found");
} 
else 
{
    Debug.Log("Key not found");
    timeText.gameObject.SetActive (true);
}
```

`PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("LevelNumber", _currentLevel);` will check to see if there's a `LevelNumber` saved on the device, if not, it will set it with the `_currentLevel` parameter. Since you're doing `levels [_currentLevel].SetActive (true);` on both the if and the else part, you don't really need that inside the if statement either. If you use the `GetInt` part of the code without the second parameter, your code will not set a default value and will be able to go into the else part.

I'm not exactly sure what `timeText.gameObject.SetActive (true);` is doing, but are you sure you need it within an if statement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its entering into that statement that's not the problem. The problem was if i press restart button in the game or if i closed and open the game means its again loading from the beginning and it showing a message key not found. I don't know how the key is missing.

Comment: @Malini check the edits, maybe something there will help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @Gnemlock I edited the answer. I missed the part where he said "it prints out key not found", my fault for trying to read fast.

Comment: This still does not appear to explain the logic of the code. *If* there is no key, the code quite clearly *sets* the key; yet, the asker notes that this happens *every time*.

Comment: Might I recommend not only taking note to read the question, but making effort to test your answer in relation to the question?

Comment: @Gnemlock It does explain it. There's no key being set at the start of the code, hence when the game is restarted, and it's checking whether that certain key is set or not, it is returning false. Even though the key is set later on, it does not matter for the code at the start because that will only ever run when the object is being initialized. It will return false every single time, without fail, if there are no other codes that affect this parameter.

Comment: eh. I can kind of see why, and I see your point. But you fail to explain *why* that is (since as it is, as far as I can tell, there is no saving, but it is fairly obvious that was intended)  In fact, it probably *is* saving (i.e. another user already reports the "error" your trying to suggest solutions for simply does not exist). If that doesn't make sense, I am not going to further explain how `PlayerPrefs` and the above logic works.